# How to dynamically add components with hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to add dynamically components to View with hooks in React Native this way:

```
const AssetDetailScreen = (props) => {

   const [details, setDetails] = React.useState('');

   React.useEffect(() => {

      getAssetDetailData()     

   });

  getAssetDetailData = () => {
    assetDetailPromise().then((data) => {

      setDetails(data)

    }).catch((error) => {

    ...
    });

  }


   assetItems = details.map((item) => {
      return(
        <Text>{item.label}</Text>
      )
    })

    return (
    <View>

      {assetItems}

    </View>
   )

}
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '... details.map...')
```

How can I solve this issue?
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by replacing this line:

```
const [details, setDetails] = React.useState('');
```

with this:

```
const [details, setDetails] = React.useState([]);
```